# How to Use ExecuteAsync in RestSharp to return variable

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, restsharp

I am having trouble with returning a variable in my async method. I am able to get the code to execute but I am not able to get the code to return the email address.

```
    public async Task<string> GetSignInName (string id)
    {

        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{id}");
        request.AddParameter("api-version", "1.6");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
        //string emailAddress = await client.ExecuteAsync<rootUser>(request, callback);

        var asyncHandler = client.ExecuteAsync<rootUser>(request, response =>
        {
            CallBack(response.Data.SignInNames);
        });

        return "test"; //should be a variable
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestSharp has built in methods for doing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP). This is invoked via `RestClient.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>` method. That will give you a response back, and the `response.Data` property will have a deserialized version of your generic argument (rootUser in your case).

```
public async Task<string> GetSignInName (string id)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{id}");
    request.AddParameter("api-version", "1.6");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");        
    var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<rootUser>(request);

    if (response.ErrorException != null)
    {
        const string message = "Error retrieving response from Windows Graph API.  Check inner details for more info.";
        var exception = new Exception(message, response.ErrorException);
        throw exception;
    }

    return response.Data.Username;
}
```

Note that `rootUser` is not a good name for a class in C#. Our normal convention is to PascalCase class names, so it should be RootUser.

Comment: Mason, thank you for your answer. It is very helpful.

Comment: Mason, is there a way to speed it up? It seems that it is taking 10 minutes to execute when it used to take 48 seconds?

Comment: You'll have to profile it and identify what the slowdown is. This alone should not have made it slower.